# index an xts object by the date nearest to the Nth of every month

Tags: r, xts

I want to index an xts object by the date nearest to the nth of every month.

In other words, I want the price of a stock on the 15th of every month.  However, the 15th is not a valid trading day for some months, because it may occur on a weekend or holiday. For those months I want to select the next following (or alternatively, next prior) valid trading day.

For example, a 'next following 15th' series over the first four months of 2015 would return observations on January 15, February 17, March 16 and April 15.

`to.period( )` effectively does this by choosing the last day of every month, regardless of whether its the 30th, 31st, 28th or 29th.  I want to  generalize this for an arbitrary day of the month.

I've been able to do this through brute-force, but I'm wondering if there is a clever way to do this.

**Update--**

Josh's answer works almost for me - my script ends up failing due to weirdness in the index value accessed by `.indexmday()`.

For instance,

```
getSymbols("SPY", from="2015-01-01")
SPY[.indexmday(SPY) == 30]
```

yields

```
           SPY.Open SPY.High SPY.Low SPY.Close SPY.Volume SPY.Adjusted
2015-03-31   207.26   208.10  206.36    206.43  126768700     205.4304
2015-05-01   209.40   210.77  209.28    210.72  103399700     209.6996
2015-07-01   207.73   208.03  206.56    207.57  129406500     207.5700
2015-07-31   211.42   211.45  210.16    210.45   97697400     210.4500
```

because the `.indexmday()` retrieves index values for May 1 and July 1 as 30, rather than 0.  I can't explain why.  I can work around it - but a workaround is so less elegant.  Anybody know why `.indexmday()` is behaving this way?

Comment: Not exactly the same, but maybe this helps: https://www.mail-archive.com/r-sig-finance@r-project.org/msg06264.html

Comment: that's interesting - thanks - but you're right its not what I'm looking to do.  The trick is, if there is a Nth date, I want that exact date; if there isn't, I want exactly the next date that exists in the series.  By brute force, I can check if the day exists, and if it doesn't, loop through dates until I find one that does exist.  I'm hopeful I can get it done without the looping...

Comment: The behavior you see with `.indexmday` is likely a timezone bug that has been fixed in the development version of xts.

Comment: I wonder why it fails for me but works for others.  Anyway, I'll use this workaround in the meantime: `SPY[.indexmday(SPY) >= 14 & .indexmday(SPY)<=25]`   Thanks!

Comment: As I said, it likely doesn't work for you because you're not using the development version of xts.

Answer (score 2):

Well, here's one way, but it gives new meaning to the word "ugly".

```
library(quantmod)    # for getSymbols
sp500 <- getSymbols("^GSPC", from="2015-01-01",auto.assign=FALSE)

result <- apply.monthly(sp500,function(x)first(x[as.POSIXlt(index(x))$mday>=15],"day"))
result
#                GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
# 2015-01-30   2013.75   2021.35  1991.47    1992.67  4276720000       1992.67
# 2015-02-27   2096.47   2101.30  2089.80    2100.34  3361750000       2100.34
# 2015-03-31   2055.35   2081.41  2055.35    2081.19  3295600000       2081.19
# 2015-04-30   2097.82   2111.91  2097.82    2106.63  4013760000       2106.63
# 2015-05-29   2122.07   2123.89  2116.81    2122.73  3092080000       2122.73
# 2015-06-30   2091.34   2091.34  2072.49    2084.43  3061570000       2084.43
# 2015-07-31   2109.01   2114.14  2102.49    2107.40  3261810000       2107.40
# 2015-08-26   2089.70   2102.87  2079.30    2102.44  2867690000       2102.44
```

So we group `sp500` by month (using `apply.monthly(...)`) and for each group extract all rows with date (`mday` in the POSIXlt object) >=15, and then find the first date in that subset.

If you look at the original `sp500` object you'll see that the data is from the correct dates, but `apply.monthly(...)` sets the index of the result to the end of the month. To get the actual dates is (AFAICT) more complicated:

```
indx <- as.Date(as.integer(apply.monthly(sp500,function(x)index(first(x[as.POSIXlt(index(x))$mday>=15],"day")))))
indx
# [1] "2015-01-15" "2015-02-17" "2015-03-16" "2015-04-15" "2015-05-15" "2015-06-15" "2015-07-15" "2015-08-17"
```

Finally, putting it all together,

```
index(result) <- indx
result
#            GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
# 2015-01-15   2013.75   2021.35  1991.47    1992.67  4276720000       1992.67
# 2015-02-17   2096.47   2101.30  2089.80    2100.34  3361750000       2100.34
# 2015-03-16   2055.35   2081.41  2055.35    2081.19  3295600000       2081.19
# 2015-04-15   2097.82   2111.91  2097.82    2106.63  4013760000       2106.63
# 2015-05-15   2122.07   2123.89  2116.81    2122.73  3092080000       2122.73
# 2015-06-15   2091.34   2091.34  2072.49    2084.43  3061570000       2084.43
# 2015-07-15   2109.01   2114.14  2102.49    2107.40  3261810000       2107.40
# 2015-08-17   2089.70   2102.87  2079.30    2102.44  2867690000       2102.44
```

Comment: Honestly, I had trouble coming up with a decent approach from scratch, but your answer helped me realize that I could do it the way I did in my answer.  So, thanks!

Answer (score 2):

I was able to come up with this approach after seeing [jlhoward's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32257951/271616), so many thanks to them! Using jlhoward's sample data, here's the one-liner:

```
R> do.call(rbind, lapply(split(sp500[.indexmday(sp500) >= 15], "months"), first))
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close GSPC.Volume GSPC.Adjusted
2015-01-15   2013.75   2021.35  1991.47    1992.67  4276720000       1992.67
2015-02-17   2096.47   2101.30  2089.80    2100.34  3361750000       2100.34
2015-03-16   2055.35   2081.41  2055.35    2081.19  3295600000       2081.19
2015-04-15   2097.82   2111.91  2097.82    2106.63  4013760000       2106.63
2015-05-15   2122.07   2123.89  2116.81    2122.73  3092080000       2122.73
2015-06-15   2091.34   2091.34  2072.49    2084.43  3061570000       2084.43
2015-07-15   2109.01   2114.14  2102.49    2107.40  3261810000       2107.40
2015-08-17   2089.70   2102.87  2079.30    2102.44  2867690000       2102.44
```

To unpack it: first you use `.indexmday` to extract all days on or after the 15th of the month. Then you call `split` on that result to create a list of all individual months, and use `lapply` and `first` to extract the first day in the data after the 15th of the month. Finally, use `do.call` and `rbind` to put everything back together.

Comment: Yes this is a better answer.

Comment: Yes this is better.  The `>=`  is the clever part I missed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the bizdays & timeDate packages helpful in this regard. bizdays is helpful for adjusting a vector of dates to the next or previous business day. You can also import the NYSE calendar from the timeDate package using rmetrics so the holidays should match up.

```
library(bizdays)
library(timeDate)

getSymbols('^GSPC',from='2010-01-01')
load_rmetrics_calendars(2010:2017)
min <- index(GSPC)[1]
max <- index(GSPC)[length(index(GSPC))]
rng2 <- seq.Date(min,max,"month")
GSPC[adjust.next(rng2, cal = "Rmetrics/NYSE")]
```

Output snippet

```
           GSPC.Open GSPC.High GSPC.Low GSPC.Close
2010-01-04   1116.56   1133.87  1116.56    1132.99
2010-02-04   1097.25   1097.25  1062.78    1063.11
2010-03-04   1119.12   1123.73  1116.66    1122.97
2010-04-05   1178.71   1187.73  1178.71    1187.44
2010-05-04   1197.50   1197.50  1168.12    1173.60
2010-06-04   1098.43   1098.43  1060.50    1064.88
2010-07-06   1028.09   1042.50  1018.35    1028.06
```